# Undefined reference to `vtable for...with RTTI support

Tags: android, android-ndk, botan

I created an application that uses RTTI support for dynamic_cast. I added "APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti" in Application.mk file but i get the error: "undefined reference to `vtable for...". If i don't use RTTI, i get the error: "error: 'dynamic_cast' not permitted with - fno-rtti"

There is the output i get:

```
    ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/vnptsofthsm/VNPTCASoftHSM/botan_impl/global_rng.o: In function `~RandomNumberGenerator':
    D:\Duongpd\Token\TMS\vnpt.example.TestSoftHSM/jni/VNPTCASoftHSM/botan_impl/../botan/../botan/rng.h:90: undefined reference to `vtable for Botan::RandomNumberGenerator'
    D:\Duongpd\Token\TMS\vnpt.example.TestSoftHSM/jni/VNPTCASoftHSM/botan_impl/../botan/../botan/rng.h:90: undefined reference to `vtable for Botan::RandomNumberGenerator'
    D:\Duongpd\Token\TMS\vnpt.example.TestSoftHSM/jni/VNPTCASoftHSM/botan_impl/../botan/../botan/rng.h:90: undefined reference to `vtable for Botan::RandomNumberGenerator'
    D:\Duongpd\Token\TMS\vnpt.example.TestSoftHSM/jni/VNPTCASoftHSM/botan_impl/../botan/../botan/rng.h:90: undefined reference to `vtable for Botan::RandomNumberGenerator'
   ./obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/vnptsofthsm/VNPTCASoftHSM/botan_impl/global_rng.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Botan::RandomNumberGenerator'
```

And here is Botan::RandomNumberGenerator :

```
class RandomNumberGenerator
   {
   public:

      static RandomNumberGenerator* make_rng();

      virtual void randomize(byte output[], size_t length) = 0;

      SecureVector<byte> random_vec(size_t bytes)
         {
         SecureVector<byte> output(bytes);
         randomize(&output[0], output.size());
         return output;
         }

      byte next_byte();

      virtual bool is_seeded() const { return true; }

      virtual void clear() = 0;

      virtual std::string name() const = 0;

      virtual void reseed(size_t bits_to_collect) = 0;

      virtual void add_entropy_source(EntropySource* source) = 0;

      virtual void add_entropy(const byte in[], size_t length) = 0;

      RandomNumberGenerator() {}
      virtual ~RandomNumberGenerator() {}
   private:
      RandomNumberGenerator(const RandomNumberGenerator&) {}
      RandomNumberGenerator& operator=(const RandomNumberGenerator&)
         { return (*this); }
   };
```

My Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DANDROID
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205886/undefined-reference-when-accessing-my-shared-library-using-jni) people succeeded to build the **botan** libraries for Android. Note that they used an older NDK, and did not have the `rtti` option at all. Most likely, you don't need it, too.

Comment: He built botan libraris with NDK tool chain R5b that is supported RTTI, but he didn't use it in his Application.mk fie. Thank you!

Comment: So, are you going to rebuild your project without RTTI?

Comment: Yes, it means that i don't use dynamic_cast in botan for Android, something need to be rewritten. Thanks for your help!