# Build Botan library for Android

Tags: android, security, botan

How can I build the cryptographic library **Botan** for Android? I am using M`ac OS 10.7` and `Eclipse IDE`.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Many Bothans died to build that library.

Comment: I am quite new in Android developement and in JNI, so I don't know how to start in order to build a c++ library from the src files. I found that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205886/undefined-reference-when-accessing-my-shared-library-using-jni , but it didn't help me. I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: I tried to follow the steps in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205886/undefined-reference-when-accessing-my-shared-library-using-jni, but here it's not clear what the "botan/botan_all.h & sources/botan_all.cpp" are.

Answer (score 2):

Please, have a look at http://marc.info/?l=botan-devel&m=132094503031485. 
There it is described what the botan_all.cpp/ botan_all.h are and how they can be generated.
Essentially, they contain all the functions of the Botan library in one file. They can be created by running:
./configure.py --cpu=arm --gen-amalgamation

In the next step you adjust your settings of the Android.mk according to ["Undefined reference" when accessing my shared library using JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205886/undefined-reference-when-accessing-my-shared-library-using-jni)

I'm not sure whether the procedure has changed since then. 
However, I hope this helps you!